# fork questions, return value and return to prompt

Tags: ruby

I have an two problems with below code. Can anyone help w/ this ?

1. How do I return values of [captured_stdout, captured_stderr] ?
2. When puts is used inside popen3, ruby doesn't return to prompt after print.
   How do I solve this ?

== code

```
#!/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'
require 'etc'

def as_user(user, &block)
  u = Etc.getpwnam(user)
  Process.fork do
      Process.uid = u.uid
      block.call(user)
  end
end

def run_cmd(cmd)
  as_user "oracle" do |user|
    puts("In block as #{user} (uid=#{Process.uid}), pid is #{Process.pid}")
    Open3.popen3(cmd) do |i,o,e,wait_thr|
        stdout = o.read
        stderr = e.read
        [stdout, stderr]
    end
  end
end

output = run_cmd("/bin/date")
puts output
```

== output

```
[root@test]# ./x2.rb
24810
In block as oracle (uid=1001), pid is 24810
[root@test]#
```

Comment: If you want to return two values from a method, put them in an array: `return [ a, b ]`.

Comment: Are you trying to return data from the subprocess to the parent process? You can't do that with return - you need to use the file descriptors popen has provided you (or some other IPC mechanism)

Comment: Frederick, Right. that is what I'm trying to do here. how do u use " the file descriptors popen has provided" here to return data ?

Comment: Jordan. I corrected that. Now any idea on my questions ?

Comment: You read and write data from them. The fact that you've got that call to fork does mean you'll need to deal with that process/subprocess too

Comment: Fredrick, again my question is how you deal with that.  Would u add code to mine here ?

Comment: @Jordan The `return` keyword is only needed if the expression being returned is not the last expression to be evaluated; and, I believe, in this case it *is* the last expression evaluated, assuming both `popen` and `as_user` return the value produced by the block. So I think `[captured_stdout, captured_stderr]` would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, @KeithBennett, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should return from the method until the popen method call (including the block you specified) has completed.  If this is true, then you'd need to declare those return variables before calling `popen`, then return them only after `popen` is complete.  Something like this:

```
def run_cmd(cmd)
  as_user "user1" do |user|
    puts("In block as #{user} (uid=#{Process.uid}), pid is #{Process.pid}")

    captured_stdout = captured_stderr = nil  # just to declare them

    Open3.popen3(cmd) do |i,o,e,wait_tnr|
       captured_stdout = o.read
       captured_stderr = e.read

       i.close
       o.close
       e.close

    end
    [captured_stdout, captured_stderr]
  end
end
```

By the way, are you sure you want to be using Ruby 1.8?  It's very ancient now and has been unsupported for a very long time.

Come to think of it, this could be simplified considerably by removing the local `captured_` variables and `close` calls:

```
def run_cmd(cmd)
  as_user "user1" do |user|
    puts("In block as #{user} (uid=#{Process.uid}), pid is #{Process.pid}")
    Open3.popen3(cmd) { |i,o,e,wait_tnr| [o.read, e.read] }
  end
end
```

To harden this a bit, you might want to add a thread join so that just in case the command closes its stdout and then needs to be running for a while after that, it gets the time to complete its work:

```
def run_cmd(cmd)
  as_user "user1" do |user|
    puts("In block as #{user} (uid=#{Process.uid}), pid is #{Process.pid}")
    Open3.popen3(cmd) do |i,o,e,wait_tnr|
      stdout = o.read
      stderr = e.read
      wait_thr.join
      [stdout, stderr]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried it and it does not return at all. Per 1.8, yes, I need to use that version b/c there are hundreds of servers w/ that ver.
[test]# ./x2.rb
125235
In block as oracle (uid=1001), pid is 125235
[rtest]#

Comment: Does the command you're executing with `popen3` return right away?  Or is it possible that it's waiting for input at some point?  Also, I don't think you need those calls to `close`; I'm pretty sure `popen3` will take care of closing anything needing closing (hopefully it has an `ensure` block to do so).

Comment: Also, please see simplification I added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Also, I think `wait_tnr` should be `wait_thr` (for "wait thread").

Comment: Keith, changed it to the simplified one and wait_tnr to wait_thr.. it returns right away. it is very short and reproducible sample code. would u actually run it yourself before further change ?

Comment: @Jon I don't understand the question.  Are you saying that this works for you and asking if there is anything I would change to make it production code? If so, I think I'd add a `wait_thr.join`.  To do this, the code in the `popen3` block would need to be reorganized a little and we'd have to add intermediate variables back.

Comment: @Jon I just added to the answer some code that would include the thread wait.

Comment: added the output of the code. my question is that  [stdout, stderr] is NEVER returned in whatever way. I didn't add thread b/c it is 1.8. can u get [stdout, stderr]  returned ?

Comment: @Jon Can you verify that `as_user` returns the value returned by the block it executes in the `Process.fork` block?  You could just put a simple value there, like 7.